# whats the difference between these statements?

Tags: python-3.x

I got different answers when i run the two statements what is the difference between the two. `math` and `chemistry`is `int` in intial condition.

```
if float(math) > 70 and float(chemistry) > 70:

if math > 70 and chemistry > 70:
```

shouldn't they give the same result? they are `int` in initial condition.

Comment: This might have something to do with the order of operations.  try putting parentheses around your inequalities and see if that gives you the same answers.

Comment: What were the values of math and chemistry when you ran the above?

Comment: Did you reassign any of math or chemistry between the two statements?

Answer (score 1):

The `float()` function converts the specified value into a floating point number. from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float)

> class float([x]) Return a floating point number constructed from a
>   number or string x.
>
> If the argument is a string, it must contain a possibly signed decimal
>   or floating point number, possibly embedded in whitespace. The
>   argument may also be [+|-]nan or [+|-]inf. Otherwise, the argument may
>   be a plain or long integer or a floating point number, and a floating
>   point number with the same value (within Python’s floating point
>   precision) is returned. If no argument is given, returns 0.0.
>
> Note When passing in a string, values for NaN and Infinity may be
>   returned, depending on the underlying C library. Float accepts the
>   strings nan, inf and -inf for NaN and positive or negative infinity.
>   The case and a leading + are ignored as well as a leading - is ignored
>   for NaN. Float always represents NaN and infinity as nan, inf or -inf.

like -

```
>>> float("3.500")
3.5
>>>float(100)
100.0
```

in your question if math and chemistry is `int` values then it should return the same result.

Comment: What Sai posted was where I was going with my comment above.

Comment: Not *necessarily*

Comment: can you explain why @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score -1):

In both cases, it will only print 'pass'. float() only converts the value in floating-point value.

```
math=90
chemistry=80
if float(math)>70 and float(chemistry)>70:
    print("pass")
if math>70 and chemistry>70:
    print("pass")`
```